# Parse: emailVerified is found nil on iPhone but works fine on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

It is really strange. When I try to call `user.objectForKey("emailVerified")` on iPhone, an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` occurred. But everything is fine on Simulator.

Is this a bug for the current version?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Found nil as I said on title

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users) which clearly states that there are 3 states of the `emailVerified` key to consider.

1) True, the email is verified.

2) False, they haven't verified yet.

3) Missing - either the user doesn't have an email or the user was created when email verification was off

What that means for you is regardless of whether or not you're on the simulator or a phone, you should be doing an optional `if let binding` since at any time, you have no guarantee that the property will exist or not.

```
if let verified = object.objectForKey("emailVerified") as? Bool {}
```

Again, read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, but I really know that and have tried that. What I said in the question is just the basic problem. In detail, if the code from your answer is executed on Simulator, it is totally fine and return `false`, but if it is executed  on iPhone, there is just no `emailVerified` field.